# How to check if 'date time' timestamp between two 'date time' timestamps

Tags: bash, logs, date

I have searched and found several ways to check if a timestamp is between two timestamps but all [methods assume](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2905688/10639803) `HH:MM:SS` format only, not taking into account **date**.

My real life scenario is timestamps input from a log file in a common format that includes date and milliseconds: `2019-11-11 19:05:55,823`.

Say I have a given timestamp `2019-11-11 19:05:55,823`, how do I find out whether it is within or outside the range:

```
2019-11-11 17:02:54,479
2019-11-12 05:13:55,998
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bash specifically, it should just be a matter of:

```
start='2019-11-11 17:02:54,479'
end='2019-11-12 05:13:55,998'
date='2019-11-11 19:05:55,823'

if LC_ALL=C command eval '[[ ! $date < $start && ! $date > $end ]]'; then 
  echo the date is in the range
fi
```

That does a lexical comparison. That works because in the C locale, those date representations sort the same lexically and chronologically.

`bash`'s `[[ < / > ]]` operators use `strcoll()` to compare strings, so use the localisation collation algorithm. In the C locale `strcoll()` is meant to work like `strcmp()`. In other locales, it compares as per the locale's conventions, so you don't get much guarantee on the outcome.

POSIXly, you could use:

```
if LC_ALL=C expr "x $date" '>=' "x $start" '&' "x $date" '<=' "x $end" > /dev/null; then
  echo the date is in the range
fi
```

Now, if you're processing log files, you'd probably want to do that comparison with `awk`. Assuming the timestamps are at the start of each line:

```
LC_ALL=C awk -v start='2019-11-11 17:02:54,479' \
             -v end='2019-11-12 05:13:55,998' '
   $0 >= start && $0 <= end' < file.log
```

would print the lines that start with a timestamp in that range.

Comment: I could be doing something wrong, but I got error "bash: syntax error in conditional expression
bash: syntax error near $start'" when I tried this

Comment: @steve, sorry, my bad, there's no such thing as `<=` and `>=` operators in `[[...]]`, you can do `<=` with `! >` (not strictly greater). See edit.

Comment: Thanks, revised approaches work perfect.

Comment: I guess use of bash `<=` can be used if the (somewhat hacky) approach of `if (( ${date//[^0-9]/} >= ${start//[^0-9]/} && ${date//[^0-9]/} <= ${end//[^0-9]/} )); then` was used